# Error importing json data using google custom search and R

Tags: json, r, google-custom-search

I am using google custom search with R. The code looks like,

```
library(httr,lib.loc = "C:\\R packages")
URL<-"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?"
key<-"key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxexxx"
cx<-"&cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
q<-"&q="
prod<-gsub(" ","+",prod)
URL<-paste0(URL,key,cx,q,prod)
```

I am able to get the json output when I copy paste the URL in my browser. However,

```
 content(GET(URL))
```

gives the following error,

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

Any input would be great. Thanks.

Comment: if the URL returns JSON, perhaps try `library(jsonlite); fromJSON(url)`

Comment: That worked! Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read JSON directly from a url using `library(jsonlite)` and the function `fromJSON()`

```
library(jsonlite)
js <- fromJSON(url)
```

Where `?fromJSON` gives

> fromJSON(txt, simplifyVector = TRUE, simplifyDataFrame = simplifyVector,
>     simplifyMatrix = simplifyVector, flatten = FALSE, ...)
>
> txt - a JSON string, URL or file